# аналог процедуры val pascal

Tags: pascal, процедуры

Есть процедура `val(string, byte/integer/longint, word)`, которая возвращает строковое представление числа из параметра 1 в численное представление, в переменную 2. 3 - говорит об ошибке, если она возникает.
В переменной 2 хранятся byte, integer или longint. Это зависит от того, какого типа переменную создал и указал в параметре.

Вот в чем проблема: Я хочу сам написать такую процедуру, но не понимаю как создать переменную в параметрах процедуры, которая становится одним из трёх типов, в зависимости от того, какую поставил в параметры при её использовании.

Например:

```
procedure vall(st: string; var byte/integer/longint; var x: word);
begin
    {...}
end;
    
var
    s: string;
    x: integer;
begin
    s:= '12345';
    vall(s, x);
    writeln(x);
end;
```

Вопрос: Как процедура сделала свой второй параметр типом integer? Что нужно написать при создании второго параметра?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перегрузка функций/процедур

```
function WhatType(const n: integer): string;
begin
    WhatType := 'integer';
end;

function WhatType(const n: real): string;
begin
    WhatType := 'real';
end;

function WhatType(const n: byte): string;
begin
    WhatType := 'byte';
end;

var
    b: byte;
    r: real;
    i: integer;

begin
    Writeln(WhatType(i));
    Writeln(WhatType(r));
    Writeln(WhatType(b));
end.
```

И советую, раз уж пишите по своему, то писать на процедурами, а функциями, и удобнее в использовании и можно будет потом применять

Comment: Спасибо за совет :)

Answer (score 3):

Точно такую процедуру создать нельзя, т.к. `val, writeln, str` и некоторые другие относятся к т.н. "магии компилятора". На самом деле компилятор подставляет на их место одну из функций с типизированным аргументом. Это можно увидеть в сгенерированном компилятором ассемблерном коде (Alt-Ctrl-C на точке останова)

```
  Val(s, intvar, c);
 007941B6 E8B578C7FF       call @UStrLAsg
  Val(s, dblvar, c);
 00794307 E88850C7FF       call @ValExt
```

Нечто похожее можно сделать с `array of const`, только аргумент будет в квадратных скобках

```
function mystr(a:array of const): string;
begin
  case a[0].VType of
    vtInteger: Result := IntToStr(a[0].vinteger);
    vtextended: Result := Format('%5.3f', [a[0].VExtended^]);
  end;
end;

memo1.Lines.Add(mystr([i]));
memo1.Lines.Add(mystr([d]));
```

или с `variant`

Comment: Я сделал аналоги функций LowerCase, UpCase, copy, pos. И аналоги процедур delete и insert. Значит можно и val (об этом говорит книга: научитесь сами их делать, что бы понять лучше работу с строками и символами).

Comment: @nx4n Это нормальные процедуры, не волшебные

Comment: :(((((((((((((((

Comment: а в pure pascal не работает overload?

Comment: @kami Да, конечно, я не на том зациклился. Дайте ответом, автору, видимо, подойдёт.